# CSS z-index issue in IE7

Tags: css, z-index

I have a problem with z-index in IE 7 and can't figure out how to solve it. I have a (superfish powered) dropdown menu which should roll out over the top of the banner below it. This works for part of the banner, but there is a section of the banner (on the left) where I have the logo overlaid on top of the banner - in this area, the dropout menu sits behind the logo image. I don't have this issue in any browser other than IE7 - can anyone see what is going on here? Thanks...

[Snipped url]

Comment: You have the issue in IE6 too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE6 and 7 have a z-index bug where each positioned element creates its own z-index stack. Try adding `position: relative` and `z-index: 200` to the parent of the navigation (`#menu`).